# Create A laravel 5.1 Api Documentation

Tags: laravel, api, laravel-5

i need to know if  there is package to make the api documentation for me 
knowing that i tried to use [laravel-apidoc-generator](https://github.com/mpociot/laravel-apidoc-generator)

but it **does not accept Laravel 5.1** . 
so any help please i don't want to make the API doc manually .

 thanks in advance .

Comment: that package supports, you need use 1.0 branch instead of 2.0

Comment: can u tell me how to do that ? @HanlinWang and thank u

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That package support laravel 5.1 in older version, use this to install

```
composer require mpociot/laravel-apidoc-generator ~1.0
```

Comment: is the use of the old package same as the new one ? @Hanlin Wang

Comment: almost same i think, you can check docs on this page https://github.com/mpociot/laravel-apidoc-generator/tree/1.7.0

Comment: last thing bro , am using the command : php artisan api:generate --routePrefix="/api/v1/* , but i got in the index.html NOTHING of the Api ? can u help me plz @Hanlin Wang

Comment: maybe try `"api/v1/*"` without leading `/`

Comment: it give me error :-   [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError]
  Call to undefined method Illuminate\Foundation\Application::bootstrapPath()

Comment: i searched this issue a bit, it might be your laravel version too old, and api generator 1.7 don't support to, you may try remove that package, and install again with a lower version `composer require mpociot/laravel-apidoc-generator 1.5.0` or `1.6.0`, if failed, try lower the version to `1.0.0`